# How to include pdo connection to User class?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I want to include a user class to my site for user login and register.
I am done with all parts except including my conection in class, actually class has it own config.php but I cant use it.
my site is live and runing with normal queries but class config doestn't let to do queries out of class.
so I need to include my own connection in class to use as `$stmt=$pdo->prepare` queries out of class.
I tried many variasions and tried really hard to make it work but I am failed on every each tries.

need your help.

> here is my config.php

```
Class Dbh{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $charset;

    protected function Connect(){
        $this->servername = "localhost";
        $this->username = "localhost";
        $this->password = "localhost";
        $this->dbname = "localhost";
        $this->charset = "UTF-8";

        try {

        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
        return $pdo;
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return "Connection Failed!: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
            }
    }
}

    $user = new User();
    $user->dbConnect(dsn, username, password);
```

> And here is my class connection part

```
class User{
    /** @var object $pdo Copy of PDO connection */
    private $pdo;
    /** @var object of the logged in user */
    private $user;
    /** @var string error msg */
    private $msg;
    /** @var int number of permitted wrong login attemps */
    private $permitedAttemps = 5;

    /**
    * Connection init function
    * @param string $conString DB connection string.
    * @param string $user DB user.
    * @param string $pass DB password.
    *
    * @return bool Returns connection success.
    */
    public function dbConnect($dsn, $username, $password){
        if(session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
            try {
                $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
                $this->pdo = $pdo;
                return true;
            }catch(PDOException $e) { 
                $this->msg = 'Connection did not work out!';
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            $this->msg = 'Session did not start.';
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into Dependency Injection and inject the database connection in the constructor of your `User` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
Class Dbh{
```

to be

```
class Dbh extends User{
```

and provided that both classes are in the same file, you will now be able to access functions in both classes.

If they are not in the same file, include the first like this:

```
include 'userClassFile.php';

class Dbh extends User{
    //Your code here
}
```

I have tried this with a very short example:

```
<?php

class classOne{
    function funcOne(){
        echo "Output";
    }
}

class classTwo extends classOne{
    function funcTwo(){
        $this->funcOne();
    }
}

$c2 = new classTwo();
$c2->funcTwo();
```

I expected to see `Output` and I saw `Output`

Comment: Damn me :( I tried to include config file into class many times and never tried to include user class in config :( thank you. So can we use that connection out of class in normal queries ?

Comment: I guess you could? I don't fully understand what you mean.